# How do I tell TypeScript that the method in my subclass returns a different type?

Tags: typescript

I have a class structure that looks a bit like this

```js
class BasicType {
    coerce(value) {
        return String(value);
    }
    read(value) {
        return this.coerce(value);
    }
}
```

The `coerce` method will always return a string, but the `read` method can return different types, depending on the subclass. For example:

```js
class FloatType extends BasicType {
    read(value) {
        return Number(super.read(value));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to put this together in TypeScript but I can't quite work out how to do it. I think I need to use generics to do this, but my first attempt at getting that work wasn't successful.

```
class BasicType<T = string> {
    coerce(value: any): string {
        return String(value);
    }
    read(value: any): T {
        return this.coerce(value);
        // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        //   'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'
        // ts(2322)
    }
}

class FloatType<T = number> extends BasicType<T> {
    read(value: any): T {
        return Number(super.read(value));
        // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        //   'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'.
        // ts(2322)
    }
}
```

This gets worse when I subclass the subclass.

```
class IntegerType<T = number> extends FloatType<T> {
    read(value: any): T {
        return Math.floor(super.read(value));
        // `return`
        // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        //   'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'.
        // ts(2322)
        // `super.read(value)`
        // Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
        // ts(2345)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I tell TypeScript that `FloatType#read` is returning a number, so it's fine to be used in `IntegerType#read` like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that `BasicType` is just an [abstract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-classes-and-members) base class that you'll never instantiate in its own.

```js
abstract class BasicType<T = string> {
    coerce(value: any): string {
        return String(value);
    }
    abstract read(value: any): T;
}

class FloatType extends BasicType<number> {
    read(value: any) {
        return Number(this.coerce(value));
    }
}

class IntegerType extends FloatType {
    read(value: any) {
        return Math.floor(super.read(value));
    }
}

class StringType extends BasicType<string> {
    read(value: any) {
        return this.coerce(value);
    }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmglrAKgJ4AOApgDz4IC8CkUOAdgOYB8CA3gFAK9ID2pKLFIAKAG7BkAV1IAuBMEaEAlAvpNmnHn11RSEaVEYIAytE0SpslQG4dvAL4PF4aHET7gAEysz5ispqCPj2zlwoaBgAYsj8wBBEZAikAB4QpIzeGNhgeEkUjNIAtiBC7Nx6pD5+sgpKqtq6VYbGCAByJWVQohAAFjhgAHSwgsJikv4qdi7O4ZHoCACSjBnMQgUp6ZnZCLHxiSSkTXxevpN1gY2Vzbz6rSYAsgl9QwBmcfw9YNJkUENnWqkab2XRzIA)

Answer (score 0):

actually we can't change the method type when overriding it. but we can set parent method type to any:

```
class BasicType {
    coerce(value) {
        return String(value);
    }
    read(value): any {
        return this.coerce(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: We could do that, but that means that `BasicType` will lose all its type safety ...

Comment: `BasicType` is more like an abstract class, it doesn't need a specific type